# OpenGL : Camera collision - problem to stop camera

Tags: kotlin, opengl, camera, collision-detection

I'm learning camera collision detection in OpenGl. I already managed to do a collision detection for AABB vs. AABB and for the camera with point vs. AABB. This is the detection for the camera:

```
   fun checkCameraQuadAABB(quad : Renderable?) : Boolean {

    val collisionX = camera.getPosition().x <= quad?.getPosition()?.x?.plus(maxX)!! && camera.getPosition().x >= quad?.getPosition()?.x?.plus(minX)
    val collisionY = camera.getPosition().y <= quad?.getPosition()?.y?.plus(maxY) && camera.getPosition().y >= quad?.getPosition()?.y?.plus(minY)
    val collisionZ = camera.getPosition().z <= quad?.getPosition()?.z?.plus(maxZ) && camera.getPosition().z >= quad?.getPosition()?.z?.plus(minZ)

    return collisionX && collisionY && collisionZ  }
```

This works o.k.

These are my camera movements for example:

```
fun moveCamera (dt: Float, t: Float) {

    this.dt = t - lastFrame
    lastFrame = t.toFloat()
    val s = 2.0f
    val cameraSpeed = dt * s

    camera.parent = null


    if (window.getKeyState(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_J) == true) {
            camera.translateLocal(Vector3f(-cameraSpeed.toFloat(), 0.0f, 0.0f)) }

    if (window.getKeyState(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_K) == true) {
            camera.translateLocal(Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -cameraSpeed.toFloat())) }

    if (window.getKeyState(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_L) == true) {
           camera.translateLocal(Vector3f(cameraSpeed.toFloat(), 0.0f, 0.0f))  } }
```

I want to stop movement of the camera, when collision is detected, but I am not able to find a way. I tried to stop movement like this:

```
  if (window.getKeyState(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_K) == true) {
         if (collisionDetectionEarth(earth, wallModule1x1Renderable) == true) {
            camera.translateLocal(Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f))
        } else {
            camera.translateLocal(Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -cameraSpeed.toFloat()))
        }
    }
```

But this is obviously not working, because the camera stops for all directions. I need a solution with a method like this:

```
    fun doCollisionCamera() {
    //check single renderable oder list of renderables
    
    if(checkCameraQuadAABB (wallModule1x1Renderable) == true) {
        //TODO set velocity 0 in the current direction, but allow other directions
               }
    else {
        //TODO move on
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to solve this. How can I check the direction and set velocity(cameraspeed) only in this direction to 0?

Comment: Are you trying to tie your camera to an object (person), or are you just avoiding going on the inside of a wall?

Comment: I want to realize fly through camera on the one side and third person on the order. This code is for fly through,  not binded to a player.The camera should stop, if collision detected for example to move foreward, but with key press j or l move to the side

Comment: I suspect that what you are looking for is non-trivial; some sort of smoothing and geometry-aware optimization. If the solids are sparse, you may be able to hand-wave a little bit; interesting question.

Comment: To solve this, I should be able to store the direction of the camera's movement and to change it per key press.  I did a lot of research now, but found nothing more than different ways for collision detection and a solution in a tutorial to change the player's direction after collision. Therefore a tuple is needed (think is data class in Kotlin) to be returned after collision. This is very complex. Maybe somebody knows a more simple solution?

Comment: What do interpenetrating solids do in your case? I'm assuming they have mass and they bounce off/stick to each other. Just set an invisible point solid with no mass and the camera's logic as the camera. _Ie_, the scenegraph might have the camera(s) in it to benefit from your collision-detection step, instead of writing a separate collision-detection algorithm for the camera.